# Distro which is preconfigured to support XPT2046 display

Tags: display

I am totally stymied on headless setup of a Raspberry Pi Zero W.

I have followed numerous guides, with no success and have decided to resort to setup with a display.

I have an
XPT2046 Resistive Touch Screen but it requires modifying configuration files and I see contradicting details on various sites, so don't want to waste any more time.

[image]
Does anyone know of a distro which supports that display natively, without having to change configuration files?

Comment: There are distros available. See [this dpciment](https://www.waveshare.com/w/upload/1/1e/RPi_LCD_User_Manual_EN.pdf), ***BUT*** they may be out of date, so it's probably best to add the drivers into the latest Raspbian or other distro, and then calibrate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[XPT2046](https://www.buydisplay.com/download/ic/XPT2046.pdf)** (not **XTP**) is not a LCD display designation, it's just resistive touch screen controller chip, which is used in several different LCD modules. That's why you can't find any distro for it.

You should find some other designation on it, e.g. ILI9341 or something similar.
Or please post images of both sides of your LCD module here.

**UPDATE**

It looks like this one is another clone of [Waveshare 3.5 inch LCD](https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/3.5inch_RPi_LCD_(A)):

They have three different models ([A](https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/3.5inch_RPi_LCD_(A)), [B](https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/3.5inch_RPi_LCD_(B)), [C](https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/3.5inch_RPi_LCD_(C))) with different drivers, but most likely, your one refers to [A](https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/3.5inch_RPi_LCD_(A)) model.

User manual: https://www.waveshare.com/w/upload/1/1e/RPi_LCD_User_Manual_EN.pdf

Driver: https://github.com/waveshare/LCD-show

Distro: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1xsvANujoImwVQvdf0n7IiUjP8BuCe2GK (could be very old but you can try it at least to check if it would work with your LCD).

If you get no luck with this one - you can try B or even C (least likely) drivers/distros.

About installation and configuration of the driver you can read [this thread](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=137149&hilit=%20waveshare#p913157).

Comment: I had forgotten this question, so searched again and found [this page](http://www.lcdwiki.com/3.5inch_RPi_Display#Step_3:_Open_terminal.28SSH.29_and_install_the_driver_on_RaspberryPi] which got the display to work, but not the touch screen functionality. If I get that working, I will report back here